# how to have a background. image perfect size for every device, and should move along with the scroll in HTML?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I tried to have an image as an background for my website and I want to place some text on the image,
I dont want the image to stay there entirely like cover even if L scroll. But, should completely cover the entire frame of any device at its initial point without any scroll.

I tried in many ways like backgound image tag.But the image does not move and I dont know how to place text on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use image attribute like size and fixed the position and finally used <div.> to create some gap in it .

.
.

Answer (score -1):

try it with background-attachment:fixed;